# Three.js ExtrudeGeometry issue for SVG Containing Ring

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to extrude an SVG icon into a 3D shape. However, ExtrudeGeometry didn't recognize that the double circle create a ring; instead it extrude the two circles separately into disks. How can I get it to extrude ring instead of two circles?

The image below is what I want to see. I rendered it using Blender.

[image: What I want to see]

This is what I got using Three.js ExtrudeGeometry:

[image: What I got]

```js
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

var scene = new THREE.Scene();

var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 100, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight);
camera.position.z = 1000;

//scene.add( cube );
let material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();
const svgLoader = new THREE.SVGLoader();
const svgData = svgLoader.parse(document.getElementById("svgDOM").outerHTML);
const svgGroup = new THREE.Group();
svgGroup.scale.y *= -1;
svgData.paths.forEach((path, i) => {
    const shapes = path.toShapes(true);

    // Each path has array of shapes
    shapes.forEach((shape, j) => {
        // Finally we can take each shape and extrude it
        const geometry = new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry(shape, {
            depth: 20,
            bevelEnabled: false
        });

        geometry.computeVertexNormals();

        // Create a mesh and add it to the group
        const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

        svgGroup.add(mesh);
    });
});
const box = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(svgGroup);
const size = new THREE.Vector3();
box.getSize(size);
const yOffset = size.y / -2;
const xOffset = size.x / -2;
svgGroup.children.forEach(item => {
    item.position.x = xOffset;
    item.position.y = yOffset;
});
scene.add( svgGroup );

var hemiLight = new THREE.HemisphereLight( 0xffffff, 0x444444 );
hemiLight.position.set( 0, 20, 0 );
scene.add( hemiLight );

var dirLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff );
dirLight.position.set( - 3, 10, - 10 );
scene.add( dirLight );


renderer.setAnimationLoop( (time) => {
    // mesh.rotation.x = time / 2000;
    // mesh.rotation.y = time / 1000;

    svgGroup.rotation.x = time / 2000;
    svgGroup.rotation.y = time / 1000;

    renderer.render( scene, camera );
});
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0px;
}
canvas {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="https://gitcdn.link/cdn/mrdoob/three.js/r134/build/three.min.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="https://gitcdn.link/cdn/mrdoob/three.js/r134/examples/js/loaders/SVGLoader.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <svg id="svgDOM" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20vmin" viewBox="0 0 860 900" version="1.1">
    <path d="M 393.531 41.593 C 314.788 48.741, 242.319 78.165, 178.500 128.902 C 163.648 140.710, 132.321 171.772, 120.403 186.509 C 61.343 259.537, 30.014 347.393, 30.011 440 C 30.003 627.339, 159.699 789.166, 343.013 830.547 C 433.058 850.873, 532.910 837.880, 614 795.285 C 652.667 774.973, 681.186 753.929, 712.557 722.557 C 738.123 696.992, 755.811 674.579, 772.977 646 C 848.860 519.666, 848.924 359.969, 773.143 234.248 C 755.550 205.060, 738.327 183.217, 712.561 157.411 C 693.571 138.392, 680.190 126.967, 660.743 113.172 C 583.896 58.658, 488.132 33.005, 393.531 41.593 M 411.500 90.598 C 365.558 94.162, 331.903 101.858, 295.742 117.068 C 252.176 135.393, 216.007 159.771, 182.464 193.417 C 125.043 251.016, 90.532 323.585, 81.845 405 C 80.264 419.814, 80.264 460.186, 81.845 475 C 89.262 544.514, 115.661 607.866, 159.721 661.885 C 171.140 675.885, 194.707 699.379, 208.790 710.803 C 262.791 754.603, 324.012 780.108, 394.500 788.170 C 408.685 789.792, 451.315 789.792, 465.500 788.170 C 524.148 781.462, 575.859 762.860, 623 731.512 C 631.525 725.843, 643.450 717.245, 649.500 712.405 C 663.698 701.048, 691.166 673.563, 702.371 659.500 C 740.271 611.936, 765.130 556.755, 774.899 498.500 C 778.486 477.113, 779.428 464.946, 779.428 440 C 779.428 415.087, 778.479 402.803, 774.925 381.708 C 766.363 330.885, 746.283 281.993, 716.569 239.615 C 692.903 205.863, 661.042 174.450, 626.500 150.815 C 579.061 118.355, 523.049 97.833, 466 92.010 C 454.765 90.864, 419.769 89.957, 411.500 90.598 M 269 216.579 C 256.852 219.776, 252.381 223.018, 232.092 243.347 C 221.579 253.881, 212.277 263.518, 211.423 264.762 C 210.569 266.006, 208.774 270.160, 207.435 273.993 C 205.346 279.973, 205 282.776, 205.001 293.731 C 205.003 327.034, 211.780 367.738, 223.195 403 C 237.352 446.736, 258.756 486.580, 287.778 523.223 C 300.784 539.646, 329.496 568.492, 345.500 581.215 C 406.744 629.906, 477.994 658.058, 555 663.991 C 582.070 666.077, 592.314 665.028, 603.993 658.975 C 605.922 657.975, 616.325 648.234, 627.110 637.329 C 642.684 621.581, 647.262 616.333, 649.353 611.828 C 655.687 598.178, 656.659 585.394, 652.397 571.802 C 649.012 561.009, 644.133 553.047, 635.948 544.960 C 625.614 534.751, 620.294 532.485, 582 521.986 L 548.500 512.801 538.500 513.268 C 520.087 514.127, 511.497 518.493, 493.468 536.152 L 480.436 548.916 468.968 545.072 C 435.162 533.739, 405.102 515.143, 379.980 490.020 C 354.465 464.505, 335.548 433.658, 324.469 399.500 L 321.226 389.500 334.454 376 C 348.728 361.431, 352.132 356.100, 355.518 343 C 358.679 330.774, 357.432 321.843, 347.563 286.044 C 337.639 250.041, 335.212 244.434, 325.069 234.069 C 317.056 225.882, 309.151 221.038, 298.198 217.603 C 288.622 214.600, 277.943 214.226, 269 216.579" stroke="none" fill="black" fill-rule="evenodd"/>
</svg>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please replace:

```js
const shapes = path.toShapes(true);
```

with:

```js
const shapes = THREE.SVGLoader.createShapes(path);
```

The default `toShapes()` method is not sufficient for the SVG spec. In order to ensure backwards compatibility, a new method `THREE.SVGLoadercreateShapes()` was added to fix shape parsing issue in context of SVG.

```js
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

var scene = new THREE.Scene();

var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 100, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight);
camera.position.z = 1000;

//scene.add( cube );
let material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();
const svgLoader = new THREE.SVGLoader();
const svgData = svgLoader.parse(document.getElementById("svgDOM").outerHTML);
const svgGroup = new THREE.Group();
svgGroup.scale.y *= -1;
svgData.paths.forEach((path, i) => {
    const shapes = THREE.SVGLoader.createShapes(path);

    // Each path has array of shapes
    shapes.forEach((shape, j) => {
        // Finally we can take each shape and extrude it
        const geometry = new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry(shape, {
            depth: 20,
            bevelEnabled: false
        });

        geometry.computeVertexNormals();

        // Create a mesh and add it to the group
        const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

        svgGroup.add(mesh);
    });
});
const box = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(svgGroup);
const size = new THREE.Vector3();
box.getSize(size);
const yOffset = size.y / -2;
const xOffset = size.x / -2;
svgGroup.children.forEach(item => {
    item.position.x = xOffset;
    item.position.y = yOffset;
});
scene.add( svgGroup );

var hemiLight = new THREE.HemisphereLight( 0xffffff, 0x444444 );
hemiLight.position.set( 0, 20, 0 );
scene.add( hemiLight );

var dirLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff );
dirLight.position.set( - 3, 10, - 10 );
scene.add( dirLight );


renderer.setAnimationLoop( (time) => {
    // mesh.rotation.x = time / 2000;
    // mesh.rotation.y = time / 1000;

    svgGroup.rotation.x = time / 2000;
    svgGroup.rotation.y = time / 1000;

    renderer.render( scene, camera );
});
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0px;
}
canvas {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="https://gitcdn.link/cdn/mrdoob/three.js/r134/build/three.min.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="https://gitcdn.link/cdn/mrdoob/three.js/r134/examples/js/loaders/SVGLoader.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <svg id="svgDOM" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20vmin" viewBox="0 0 860 900" version="1.1">
    <path d="M 393.531 41.593 C 314.788 48.741, 242.319 78.165, 178.500 128.902 C 163.648 140.710, 132.321 171.772, 120.403 186.509 C 61.343 259.537, 30.014 347.393, 30.011 440 C 30.003 627.339, 159.699 789.166, 343.013 830.547 C 433.058 850.873, 532.910 837.880, 614 795.285 C 652.667 774.973, 681.186 753.929, 712.557 722.557 C 738.123 696.992, 755.811 674.579, 772.977 646 C 848.860 519.666, 848.924 359.969, 773.143 234.248 C 755.550 205.060, 738.327 183.217, 712.561 157.411 C 693.571 138.392, 680.190 126.967, 660.743 113.172 C 583.896 58.658, 488.132 33.005, 393.531 41.593 M 411.500 90.598 C 365.558 94.162, 331.903 101.858, 295.742 117.068 C 252.176 135.393, 216.007 159.771, 182.464 193.417 C 125.043 251.016, 90.532 323.585, 81.845 405 C 80.264 419.814, 80.264 460.186, 81.845 475 C 89.262 544.514, 115.661 607.866, 159.721 661.885 C 171.140 675.885, 194.707 699.379, 208.790 710.803 C 262.791 754.603, 324.012 780.108, 394.500 788.170 C 408.685 789.792, 451.315 789.792, 465.500 788.170 C 524.148 781.462, 575.859 762.860, 623 731.512 C 631.525 725.843, 643.450 717.245, 649.500 712.405 C 663.698 701.048, 691.166 673.563, 702.371 659.500 C 740.271 611.936, 765.130 556.755, 774.899 498.500 C 778.486 477.113, 779.428 464.946, 779.428 440 C 779.428 415.087, 778.479 402.803, 774.925 381.708 C 766.363 330.885, 746.283 281.993, 716.569 239.615 C 692.903 205.863, 661.042 174.450, 626.500 150.815 C 579.061 118.355, 523.049 97.833, 466 92.010 C 454.765 90.864, 419.769 89.957, 411.500 90.598 M 269 216.579 C 256.852 219.776, 252.381 223.018, 232.092 243.347 C 221.579 253.881, 212.277 263.518, 211.423 264.762 C 210.569 266.006, 208.774 270.160, 207.435 273.993 C 205.346 279.973, 205 282.776, 205.001 293.731 C 205.003 327.034, 211.780 367.738, 223.195 403 C 237.352 446.736, 258.756 486.580, 287.778 523.223 C 300.784 539.646, 329.496 568.492, 345.500 581.215 C 406.744 629.906, 477.994 658.058, 555 663.991 C 582.070 666.077, 592.314 665.028, 603.993 658.975 C 605.922 657.975, 616.325 648.234, 627.110 637.329 C 642.684 621.581, 647.262 616.333, 649.353 611.828 C 655.687 598.178, 656.659 585.394, 652.397 571.802 C 649.012 561.009, 644.133 553.047, 635.948 544.960 C 625.614 534.751, 620.294 532.485, 582 521.986 L 548.500 512.801 538.500 513.268 C 520.087 514.127, 511.497 518.493, 493.468 536.152 L 480.436 548.916 468.968 545.072 C 435.162 533.739, 405.102 515.143, 379.980 490.020 C 354.465 464.505, 335.548 433.658, 324.469 399.500 L 321.226 389.500 334.454 376 C 348.728 361.431, 352.132 356.100, 355.518 343 C 358.679 330.774, 357.432 321.843, 347.563 286.044 C 337.639 250.041, 335.212 244.434, 325.069 234.069 C 317.056 225.882, 309.151 221.038, 298.198 217.603 C 288.622 214.600, 277.943 214.226, 269 216.579" stroke="none" fill="black" fill-rule="evenodd"/>
</svg>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This solution worked. Ended 2 days of hell for me.